# serialPort.Read, not right string

Tags: serial-port

[image: screen]

```
public string s;                                                            
public byte[] gest = new byte[9];
public string get_s;
public bool m = false;


    if (serialPort.Read(gest, 0, 7) != 0)                            // gest 读进来   
    {
        //  if(sizeof(gest) == 7)
        s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(gest, 0, 8);
    }


    Debug.Log(s);
```

I am expecting the rescults like : "!#-3333" or "!#-4444" 
But the first string is "!"

Could anyone help?

Comment: What language is this?  Please tag your post with the correct language tag.

Comment: Thx, it is fixed now. C#        The problem is the differences between serialPort.Read() and serialPort.ReadChar,  althoug the tutorial says it is goog to use Read() to obtain the sequence of the data, but it is wrong with the first byte and string ......                                                          
           while (s.Length < 7)
        {
            char character = (char)serialPort.ReadChar();             /// /// 
            s += character.ToString();
        }
        Debug.Log(s);
        serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();